# Why did Julia not kill this character?

Tags: cowboy-bebop, cowboy-bebop-2021

Near the end of the first season of the live-action version of *Cowboy Bebop*, Julia finds that she has

> Vicious

in her power and has the opportunity to kill him. However, rather than doing so, she appears to spin the chamber of her pistol and play a game of bullet roulette, which fails to kill him. She then walks away with a threat to try again the following day.

However, this is after she has:

1. Just shot the person whom she *actually* was in love with (Fearless/Spike), and who was *not* the person who had been physically and verbally abusing her for several years, without any such games.
2. Explicitly asked said person to shoot Vicious dead on the spot.
3. Conspired with another member of the syndicate to kill him.
4. Already said that there is no reason for anyone to see Vicious in public, ever, and that as such he is of no use to her (and if there ever emerged such a necessity, it seems unlikely that she could do it safely).

As such, why does Julia waste her time playing bullet roulette with Vicious, when it seems that she has every reason to want him dead immediately, and few compunctions about killing him? What were her motivations?

Comment: I don't know, maybe she is not evil enough to committ murder, merely close to it.  To paraphrase JFK "Ask no twhy characters are not evil enough to kille, ask rather why they are evil enough to kill".

Comment: @M.A. Golding - She shot her ex-boyfriend, whom she admitted she still cared about, in the chest, making him fall backwards through a window hundreds of feet. If that is not being willing to commit murder....

Comment: “Something Vimes had learned as a young guard drifted up from memory. If you have to look along the shaft of an arrow from the wrong end, if a man has you entirely at his mercy, then hope like hell that man is an evil man. Because the evil like power, power over people, and they want to see you in fear. They want you to know you're going to die. So they'll talk. They'll gloat. They'll watch you squirm. They'll put off the moment of murder like another man will put off a good cigar. So hope like hell your captor is an evil man. A good man will kill you with hardly a word.” -Terry Pratchett

Comment: Perhaps she thought she was showing Fearless a mercy by giving him a 'quick death' (at least so she thought) and obviously she wants to torment Viscious.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be it shows the change in her attitude - from the innocent ingenue she was, to the abused trophy wife to a sadist, just like Vicious. She doesn't just want to be 'free' of Vicious and have a quiet life with Fearless/Spike - she is trying to take back control, ironically becoming just like Vicious, just even more manipulative. She *wants* him to feel fear, and break, just as she did.

She's no longer the Julia the innocent singer - and is colder and harder. I suspect even asking Spike to join her was an attempt at manipulating him.

I suspect this would be fleshed out more in the next season had it happened - and that *was* a twist ending - so we might never know.

Comment: https://gizmodo.com/cowboy-bebops-elena-satine-and-alex-kessell-on-julia-an-1848065665 this interview seems to back this up partially. Putting this here so I can incorporate it into my answer over the weekend

Comment: I felt the implication was that she was going to kill him (and indeed, could have) but she wants to drag it out. Maybe he dies today, maybe he dies tomorrow. Either way he dies.

Comment: @Valorum To paraphrase certain Narn... He will know pain. Then he will know fear. Then he will die....